# checking for coinciding lines in a collision

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3

this is some kind of followup to my last question.
i needed to find an algorithm, which detects lines crossing / overlapping.

the following code worked well for most cases, but does not correctly deal with coinciding lines:

```
public static function checkLinesIntersection(p_a:Point,p_b:Point,p_c:Point,p_d:Point):Point
{

    // Denominator
    var d:Number = (p_d.y - p_c.y) * (p_b.x - p_a.x) - (p_d.x - p_c.x) * (p_b.y - p_a.y);

    //
    var n_a:Number = (p_d.x - p_c.x) * (p_a.y - p_c.y) - (p_d.y - p_c.y) * (p_a.x - p_c.x);
    var n_b:Number = (p_b.x - p_a.x) * (p_a.y - p_c.y) - (p_b.y - p_a.y) * (p_a.x - p_c.x);

    var ua:Number = n_a / d;
    var ub:Number = n_b / d;

    var p_intersection:Point = new Point();

    //coincidental but also happenes when lines are just aligned on the same plane
    if(d + n_a + n_b == 0){

        //how can i find if the lines really coincide and are not just in alignment, or parallel?

    };
    if ((ua >= 0 && ua <= 1 && ub >= 0 && ub <= 1))
    {
        p_intersection.x = p_a.x + (ua * (p_b.x - p_a.x));
        p_intersection.y = p_a.y + (ua * (p_b.y - p_a.y));
        return p_intersection;
    }
    return null;
}
```

how can i refine the code, so that only coinciding and not parallel lines are evaluated as an intersection?

thanks a lot!

Comment: What is an example for which it doesn't work?  What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: You must differenciate lines and segments. I'm guessing you are talking about segments?

Comment: hi!
@ Oli Charlesworth:
i checked the following situation:
this works and is waht i want to achieve
( the user is not allow to draw shapes with crossing lines)
http://i.imgur.com/Ss8I8.png

however this one:

http://i.imgur.com/fYwSP.png
\n
should be correct, but the above code cannot distinguish between a parallel and a coinciding one.

@ lcfseth

yes, i huess i mean segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting two coinciding lines is easy. all you need to do, is take the lower point of both segments, let's call them m1,m2 and the higher points M1,M2.

Now check if m1M2 intersects m2M1.

If they don't then they are on the same line.

Now just check that the lower segment high end is in the higher segment.
[image: Illustration]

Comment: Now check if m1M2 intersects m2M1.  - these two points will always intersect, even if on the same line, the only difference will be the number of points they intersect at.